# Translate Drupal's built-in English to another kind of English

Tags: i18n-l10n

I need to translate the American English Drupal core currently provides out of the box to a variation of English. I know I can use string overrides but there are too many that I need to override. Essentially I need to create my own custom language based off english. Suggestions?

Comment: If you're looking for en-GB (British English), that's already supported by Drupal, and will show up when you "Add a language".

Comment: That's ok. I need to create a custom "English".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the Locale module, which is provided by core.  Steps are for Drupal 7.  This assumes you want to completely replace the built-in English with your own custom version of English (which will still show the strings for the built-in English unless you have translated/edited them).

1. Enable the locale module.
2. Go to languages admin (/admin/config/regional/language).
3. Click *edit* for the English (built-in) language.  Add *en* as the **Path prefix** (this will allow you to add your own language without a path prefix.)  Save.
4. Click "Add a language"
5. Choose "Custom language", set a language code, set both language names to *English*,  leave **Path prefix** and **Language domain** blank, and choose *Left to right* for the **Direction**.
6. Go back to the language list (/admin/config/regional/language) and set your new English as the default language.  Then uncheck *Enabled* for the built-in English.
7. Translate all the strings you want to modify on the translation screen (/admin/config/regional/translate/translate).

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal core locale module is all you need to do this.  Enable it if required, then navigate to `Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language`and notice the two tabs "Export" and "Import".

These allow you to export and import `.po` files with translations from the default (American English) into your default language.  `.po`-fils are text files. The format is very simple and consists of pairs like these (the line starting with "#" is a comment):

```
#: src/colors.inc:36
msgid "color"
msgstr "colour"
```

So just export all the strings of your site, then translate those that needs translation, and import.

(You may want to create a custom language code for your custom english, just to be able to toggle between American english and custom english, instead of just overrwriting the American english.)